# SQL Insert Statement Inserting 2 records instead of 1

Tags: php, mysql

I've seen some people have the same issue, but different scenarios. And searching just gives me 'how to use joins'.

When I execute this through my php page, two records are inserted. One with the content, and one with just the date. I can't seem to find where the date field is being executed. I've had this issue in the past, but with a past version of mySQL and with depreciated values, so using the new values is someone newer to me.

Below is my php and sql statement:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('server', 'username', 'password');
if (!$link) {
die('Could Not Connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
else echo 'Connected Succesffully';
mysqli_select_db($link, 'database');

mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO tblcc 
                     (date , production , productionco , city , state , 
                      genre , type , details , part1 , gender1 , 
                      char1 , part2 , gender2 , char2 , part3 ,
                      gender3 , char3 , part4 , gender4 , char4 , part5 ,
                      gender5 , char5)
            VALUES(now() , '$_POST[production]' , '$_POST[productionco]' , '$_POST[city]' ,  '$_POST[state]' ,
                  '$_POST[genre]' , '$_POST[type]' , '$_POST[details]' , '$_POST[part1]' , '$_POST[gender1]' , 
                  '$_POST[char1]' , '$_POST[part2]' , '$_POST[gender2]' , '$_POST[char2]' , '$_POST[part3]' , 
                  '$_POST[gender3]' , '$_POST[char3]' , '$_POST[part4]' , '$_POST[gender4]' , '$_POST[char4]' ,
                  '$_POST[part5]' , '$_POST[gender5]', $_POST[char5]')");

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

The HTML:

```
<form action="http://enhstudios.com/bc1/submitcc.php/" method="post">
    <table border="3" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <th>Production:</th>
        <th>Production Company:</th>
        <th colspan="2">Location:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="production"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="productionco"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="city"></td>
        <td><select name="state">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
            <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
            <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
            <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
            <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
            <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Genre:</th>
        <th>Type:</th>
        <th colspan="2">Details:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><select name="genre">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Action">Action</option>
            <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
            <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
            <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
            <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name="type">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Feature Length">Feature Length</option>
            <option value="Mini-Series">Mini-Series</option>
            <option value="Short">Short</option>
            <option value="Web Series">Web Series</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2"><textarea maxlength="255" rows="5" cols="30" name="details"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">Parts:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Role Type:</th>
        <th>Gender:</th>
        <th colspan="2">Character:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><select name="part1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Extra">Extra</option>
            <option value="Leading">Leading</option>
            <option value="Supporting">Supporting</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name="gender1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="char1">
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><select name="part2">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Extra">Extra</option>
            <option value="Leading">Leading</option>
            <option value="Supporting">Supporting</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name="gender2">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="char2">
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><select name="part3">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Extra">Extra</option>
            <option value="Leading">Leading</option>
            <option value="Supporting">Supporting</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name="gender3">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="char3">
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><select name="part4">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Extra">Extra</option>
            <option value="Leading">Leading</option>
            <option value="Supporting">Supporting</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name="gender4">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="char4">
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><select name="part5">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Extra">Extra</option>
            <option value="Leading">Leading</option>
            <option value="Supporting">Supporting</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name="gender5">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="char5">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: can you post your form here? the page that called this

Comment: That PHP code will not create 2 rows. However if you are calling it twice that might explain it. But as you dont show how you call it we cannot know for sure. I would guess that you are calling this code from an AJAX call, if you look at what `event.preventDefault()` does it would solve your problem

Comment: I added a link to the form; I think it looks fine, compared to other forms at least. What I'm not understanding is it's not posting anything else in the second record, just the date. I'm not collecting any date data, it's being set by the server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the "issue". I nestled the form inside the table instead of the table inside the form.